# flex/actionscript embed large fonts

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, fonts

i have (business card designer) in flex 3.6 & using some large sized fonts for embedding them at run-time. Some fonts are damn fat to load them in browser ie - Chinese fonts(10 to 20 mb).
i have tried fontForge to reduce font size but it does not make drastic change. I have seen example of pixlr where fonts are being loaded speedily. 
What Can We Do For Overcome This Problem---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to create a .swf file with some. all or just one of these large Fonts and them Import these ??? regards aktell

Comment: i have created swf for font but it is also too much heavy